# ToolTip for autogenerated column Gridview of silveright

Tags: silverlight, gridview, telerik, tooltip

here is what i tried

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType ="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell">
                 <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>\
                </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
```

here this is working fine if `Value="toool tip text"` but i want to dispaly header text as tooltip what i assign to value so it should do work for me right now its givin error to me for the above line of code

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a blogpost, which you can read for further detail: [Assign ToolTip to dynamically created colum of silverlight Gridview and How to create style for element runtime](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/08/assign-tooltip-to-dynamically-created.html)

I resolved issue following is way you can add tooltip for the autogenerated column in Telerik silverlight grid view same thing will work with silverlight grid view just need to change classes minor modification

```
private void EditableGV_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
   var style = new Style(typeof(GridViewHeaderCell));
   style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, column.UniqueName));
   column.HeaderCellStyle = style; 
}
```

Comment: In the future, please be sure to include your affiliation when linking to external content.